# CORS error when accessing IceCast stream even though Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set properly

Tags: cors, web-audio-api, icecast

I'm trying to visualize audio stream from another website via setting stream URL as `<audio>` element's `<source>` and then using [`createMediaElementSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource). The server runs IceCast and here are the response headers:

```
Accept-Ranges:none
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store
Connection:close
Content-Type:audio/mpeg
Expires:Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
ice-audio-info:bitrate=128
icy-br:128
icy-br:128
icy-description:NONSTOP
icy-genre:Hit
icy-name:UltRadio
icy-pub:0
icy-url:http://ultradio.ru
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Icecast 2.3.3-kh11
```

As you can see the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*` is there yet I'm still getting this error:

```
MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions
```

Apparently IceCast version 2.4.1+ is required for proper CORS features. But what exactly has been changed in this version? What apart from `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` can prevent cross-origin access?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't give any example code, but did you remember to add crossorigin="anonymous" (or other appropriate value) for your audio tag?

Comment: Thnk you! I actually did try this but I was adding `crossorigin="anonymous"` afterwards an audio element was created. When I add this tag simultaneously with audio element, it works.